# A generic catch-version for exceptions?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have a sequelize database that validates data and throws errors.

I know I can do something like this to catch and output my errors:

```
 User.build()
 .catch(Sequelize.ValidationError, function (err) {
            // respond with validation errors
            return res.status(422).send(err.errors);
        })
 .catch(function (err) {
       // every other error
       return res.status(400).send({
           message: err.message
       });
```

But I don't want to add it to every single request, is there some generic way to catch theese errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a custom method to `req` (or `res`) that will resolve the promise and handle any errors:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  req.resolve = (promise) => {
    return promise.catch(Sequelize.ValidationError, err => {
      // respond with validation errors
      return res.status(422).send(err.errors);
    }).catch(err => {
      // every other error
      return res.status(400).send({ message: err.message });
    });
  });
  next();
});
```

Usage (provided that the middleware above is added before your routes):

```
router.post('/user', (req, res) => {
  req.resolve(User.build()).then(user => res.json(user));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**ES.next version (2016)**:

you can use async functions that `throw` using this wrapper function copied from the official strongloop website:

```
let wrap = fn => (...args) => fn(...args).catch(args[2]);
```

then make the function in your router/controller like that:

```
router.post('/fn/email', wrap(async function(req, res) { ...throw new Error(); }
```

and finally have a normal catch all errors middleware:

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) { console.log(err); }
```

Obviously for this to work you need the [babel](http://babeljs.io) transpiler currently

Comment: what is this babel you speak of?

Comment: read my updated comment. If you are writing any javascript code you should at least know what babel is nowadays